# Inverse Limit of set

Tags: limits

If      $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  a_{1} +  a_{2} + a_{3} + ... +a_{n}= L$$
Does it follow that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{a_{1}}+   \frac{1}{a_{2}} +  \frac{1}{a_{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{a_{n}}= \frac{1}{L} \text{?}$$

Comment: if $2+2=4$ then $\frac12+\frac12=\frac14$

Comment: Definitely not.  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n} = \frac{1}{L}$, provided $L \neq 0$

Comment: Note you are missing assumptions on the $a_i$, e.g. if $a_i=0$ you might have trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $\lim_{n \to \infty}  a_{1} +  a_{2} + a_{3} + ... +a_{n}= L$ then you have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=L$ (which is exactly the same thing just written differently) and series can only be convergent if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$ which means that after some $n_0$ the absolute value of the terms $\frac {1}{a_n}$  will be bigger and bigger and so $|\frac {1}{a_n}|$ will approach infinity, so not only that your two limits will not be reciprocals but, as it seems, both cannot exist simultaneously?

Comment: Nitpick.  Not if $a_n$ is allowed to be negative.  And if lim $\sum a_n = 0$ then $\sum 1/a_n$ diverging is acceptable.

Comment: @Ante, should "both cannot exist" be "both cannot exist simultaneously"? I think I just read it funny the way you wrote it. But dig it.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb Good point, but that is implicit, and I think that there is no need to state it explicitly. If you want,  I will edit the answer and add that word?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you're taking reciprocals it doesn't preserve addition. For example if $L=10$ then $$L=2+2+2+4$$
but $$\frac 12 +\frac 12 +\frac 12 +\frac 14 = \frac 74 \neq \frac 1{10}$$ however $$\frac 1L= \frac 1{10}= \frac {1}{2+2+2+4}$$

Answer (score 0):

God NO!  Consider $a_n = \frac 1 {2^n}$.  $\lim 1/2 + 14 + 1/8 + ..... + 1/2^n= 1$.  So does it follow that $1/a_n = 2^n$ that $\lim 2 + 4 + ..... + 2^n = 1/1 = 1$?

In fact if $a_n > 0$ that would imply $a_n -> 0$ (as the sum would diverge) so $1/a_n -> \infty$ so lim of the sum of $1/a_n$ diverges.  So unless $\lim \sum a_n = 0$ this isn't true.